# How to change the HTTP Request Content Type for FLURL Client?

Tags: c#, http-headers, flurl

I am using flurl to submit HTTP request and this is very useful. Now I need to change the "**Content-Type"** header for some of the requests to **"application/json;odata=verbose"**

```
    public async Task<Job> AddJob()
    {

        var flurlClient = GetBaseUrlForGetOperations("Jobs").WithHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;odata=verbose");
        return await flurlClient.PostJsonAsync(new
        {
            //Some parameters here which are not the problem since tested with Postman

        }).ReceiveJson<Job>();
    }

    private IFlurlClient GetBaseUrlForOperations(string resource)
    {
        var url = _azureApiUrl
            .AppendPathSegment("api")
            .AppendPathSegment(resource)
            .WithOAuthBearerToken(AzureAuthentication.AccessToken)
            .WithHeader("x-ms-version", "2.11")
            .WithHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        return url;
    }
```

You can see how I tried to add the header above (`.WithHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;odata=verbose")`)

Unfortunately this gives me following error:

> "InvalidOperationException: Misused header name. Make sure request
>   headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with
>   HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects."

I also tried flurl's "ConfigureHttpClient" method but could not find how/where to set the content type header.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add content header to Flurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32829763/how-to-add-content-header-to-flurl)

Comment: You need to create a `HttpRequestMessage` add a content and specify the type there

Comment: This is glitch that's fixed in [2.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Flurl.Http/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments and another post I found (will add reference when I find it again)  have pointed me to the right direction.
The solution for my problem looks like:

```
        var jobInJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(job);
        var json = new StringContent(jobInJson, Encoding.UTF8);
        json.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json; odata=verbose");

        var flurClient = GetBaseUrlForOperations("Jobs");

        return await flurClient.PostAsync(json).ReceiveJson<Job>();
```

Edit: Found the related SO question: [Azure encoding job via REST Fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28451341/azure-encoding-job-via-rest-fails)

Comment: That'll work. I posted an alternative answer that you might like even better.

Answer (score 5):

**This answer is outdated. Upgrade to [latest version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Flurl.Http/) (2.0 or above) and the problem goes away.**

It turns out the [real issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10679340/62600) has to do with how the `System.Net.Http` APIs validate headers. It makes a distinction between request-level headers and content-level headers, which I've always found a bit odd since raw HTTP makes no such distinction (except perhaps in multipart scenarios). Flurl's `WithHeader` adds headers to the `HttpRequestMessage` object but is failing validation for `Content-Type`, which it expects to be added to the `HttpContent` object.

Those APIs do allow you to skip validation, and although Flurl doesn't expose it directly, you can get under the hood pretty easily, without breaking the fluent chain:

```
return await GetBaseUrlForGetOperations("Jobs")
    .ConfigureHttpClient(c => c.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json;odata=verbose"))
    .PostJsonAsync(new { ... })
    .ReceiveJson<Job>();
```

This is probably the best way to do what you need and still take advantage of Flurl's goodness, i.e. not have to directly deal with serialization, `HttpContent` objects, etc.

I'm strongly considering changing Flurl's `AddHeader(s)` implementations to use `TryAddWithoutValidation` based on this issue.

Comment: thanks! very happy with this, thankfully, I can use flurl now with an Api that requires a header that system.net.http considers invalid

Answer (score 1):

```
public static class Utils
{
    public static IFlurlClient GetBaseUrlForOperations(string resource)
    {
        var _apiUrl = "https://api.mobile.azure.com/v0.1/apps/";

        var url = _apiUrl
            .AppendPathSegment("Red-Space")
            .AppendPathSegment("HD")
            .AppendPathSegment("push")
            .AppendPathSegment("notifications")
            .WithHeader("Accept", "application/json")
            .WithHeader("X-API-Token", "myapitocken");

            return url;
    }

    public static async Task Invia()
    {
        FlurlClient _client;
        PushMessage pushMessage = new PushMessage();
        pushMessage.notification_content = new NotificationContent();

        try
        {
            var flurClient = Utils.GetBaseUrlForOperations("risorsa");
            // News news = (News)contentService.GetById(node.Id);
            //pushMessage.notification_target.type = "";
            pushMessage.notification_content.name = "A2";
            // pushMessage.notification_content.title = node.GetValue("TitoloNews").ToString();
            pushMessage.notification_content.title = "Titolo";
            pushMessage.notification_content.body = "Contenuto";
            var jobInJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pushMessage);
            var json = new StringContent(jobInJson, Encoding.UTF8);
            json.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");
            dynamic data2 = await flurClient.PostAsync(json).ReceiveJson();
            var expandoDic = (IDictionary<string, object>)data2;
            var name = expandoDic["notification_id"];
            Console.WriteLine(name);
        }
        catch (FlurlHttpTimeoutException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType + " " + ex);
        }
        catch (FlurlHttpException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType + " " + ex);
            if (ex.Call.Response != null)
                Console.WriteLine("Failed with response code " + ex.Call.Response.StatusCode);
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Totally failed before getting a response! " + ex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType + " " + ex);
        }
    }
}

public class NotificationTarget
{
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class CustomData {}

public class NotificationContent
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string body { get; set; }
    public CustomData custom_data { get; set; }
}

public class PushMessage
{
    public NotificationTarget notification_target { get; set; }
    public NotificationContent notification_content { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Am I allowed to post 3 answers to the same question? :)

[Upgrade.](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Flurl.Http/) Flurl.Http 2.0 includes the following enhancements to headers:

1. `WithHeader(s)` now uses `TryAddWithoutValidation` under the hood. With that change alone, the OP's code will work as originally posted.
2. Headers are now set at the request level, which solves [another known issue](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/issues/157).
3. When using `SetHeaders` with object notation, [underscores in property names will be converted to hyphens](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/issues/44) in the header names, since hyphens in headers are very common, underscores are not, and hyphens are not allowed in C# identifiers.

This will be useful in your case:

```
.WithHeaders(new {
    x_ms_version = "2.11",
    Accept = "application/json"
});
```

Comment: Hi Todd, could you please add a hint / edit your answer from July 14th 2017. This one here is pretty easy to miss. Thanks :-)

Comment: I did. Did you miss the part in bold? ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an OData expert and I don't know what API you're calling (SharePoint?), but based on most examples I've seen, what you typically want to do is ask the server to send verbose OData in the response, rather than declare that you're sending it in the request. In other words, you want to set the `;odata=verbose` bit on the **Accept** header, not **Content-Type**. `application/json` should be good enough for Content-Type, and Flurl will set that for you automatically, so just try this change and see if it works:

```
.WithHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
```

Comment: I am using the Azure Media Services API. As described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/media/operations/job setting the accept header as you described should be enough. But it works only if I set the Content-Type header to the same